# Xcode 10 new update?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Can anyone explain me about the new update in Xcode 10 editor regarding the UILabel inspector property **"Marquee on Ancestor Focus"** for controlling scrolling behaviour.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes/interface_builder_release_notes_for_xcode_10

I tried to access this marquee attribute, but unfortunate I haven't find any. Has anyone tried the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you're trying to access it through an watchOS or iOS Storyboard.

You can read it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/2967087-enablesmarqueewhenancestorfocuse) that it's a **tvOS property only**.

This image validates its availability through `IBInspector` - but only in **tvOS**.

[image]

Comment: I was using iOS storyboard.